# Overriding of button in android, change layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

In my project, `Button` added to the view dynamically and how many number of button is also unknown. So to carry these button i have created `linearlayout(horizonatal)`. Problem is when button exceeded several limit(say 5) then 6 button wont draw over the screen, i don't want scroll, i want all the button on screen, wont matter if buttons will created below the buttons that already created. How to achieve this. How to know that screen is filled with buttons?

Comment: If you can add some code, would be helpful for others to reproduce the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will have to dynamically keep track of how much screen space is being occupied by buttons based on the height and potentially the width of the screen. To get the screen size in **pixels** you can do something like

```java
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 display.getSize(size);
 int width = size.x;
 int height = size.y;
```

or

```java
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

// displayMetrics.heightPixels will give you the height
// displayMetrics.widthPixels will give you the width
```

Then you just have to compare this to the total number of pixels being used by buttons. Keep a counter of buttons created. Since you know the pixel height per button, just multiply that by the number of buttons created and you will know if it exceeds the height.

If you need the size in **dp** you can divide the values from `displayMetrics.heightPixels` or `displayMetrics.widthPixels` by the density

`float dp = displayMetrics.heightPixels/displayMetrics.density`